# Two-dimensional bounded area defined parametrically

Tags: computational-geometry

How do I go about defining this area without using a piecewise function?

I think it has something to do with Bilinear Surfaces but I'm not sure how to get started.

[image: Graph showing an area composed of a square region adjoining a triangular region]

Comment: What kind of properties are you after for that surface?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is bilinear mapping, which works for every convex quadrilateral.

Let $A, B, C, D$ be the vertices of a quadrilateral $Q$ in the plane, in this order.

Then $f(u,v)=(1-u)(1-v)A + u(1-v)B + uvC + (1-u)vD$ maps the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ to $Q$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What, [no MathJax](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/should-we-have-mathjax-support) ? :-(

Comment: Yep, looks like it's not working yet :(. Would you mind just using plain code formatting for time being, so all those symbols won't distract from the formulas?

Comment: I've added this question to the [list of examples on meta](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/should-we-have-mathjax-support) to add to the case for adding MathJax to our site.

Comment: "which works for _every quadrilateral_." Unless I've messed up my "back of the envelope sketch", I think you need to amend that to "every _convex_ quadrilateral".

Comment: @ratchet, MathJax, yeah!